# Angular.js ng-click event not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS, and I'm trying to implement a page to display, add, edit and delete objects from a REST API. I have functions to add, edit and delete items bound to `ng-click`, but the edit and delete events are not firing. The only difference between the add and edit/delete bindings seems to be that the edit/delete `ng-click`s are inside an `ng-repeat`.

JavaScript code:

```js
process_errors = function(rejection) {
    // Error processing code
}

var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngResource']);

exampleApp.factory('Example', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/v1/example/:example_id', {example_id:'@id'});
}]);
exampleApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = $.cookie('csrftoken');
}]);

exampleApp.controller('exampleListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Example',
function($scope, Example) {
    $scope.examples = Example.query();
    $scope.newExample = new Example();
    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.newExample.$save().then(function(result){
            $scope.examples.push(result);
        }).then(function() {
            $scope.newExample = new Example();
        }, process_errors);
    }
    $scope.editExample = function(example) {
        console.log('editing');
        var idx = $scope.examples.indexOf(example);
        $scope.examples[idx].$save().then(function(result) {
        }, function(rejection) {
            process_errors(rejection);
            $scope.editMode = true;
        });
    }
    $scope.deleteExample = function(example) {
        console.log('deletion');
        example.$delete().then(function(){
            var idx = $scope.examples.indexOf(example);
            $scope.examples.splice(idx, 1);
        });
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="content-container" ng-app="exampleApp">
    <table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="exampleListCtrl">
        <thead>
            <!-- Table headers -->
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newExample.start_date" placeholder="2013-11-25"></input></td>
                    <!-- more fields in the same format -->
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()">Add</button></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="example in examples">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <td>
                        <span ng-hide="editMode">{{example.start_date}}</span>
                        <input ng-show="editMode" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="example.start_date" value="{{example.start_date}}"></input>
                    </td>
                    <!-- more fields in the same format -->
                    <td>
                        <button ng-hide='editMode' class="btn btn-default" ng-click="editMode = true;">Edit</button>
                        <button ng-show='editMode' class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editExample(example); editMode = false">Save</button>
                    </td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteExample(example)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I've also tried binding the functions to `$parent.editExample(example)`.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Forgive me if I am missing it, but where is `idx` instantiated? I only see it in those two functions, so could that be your problem? `var idx = `

Comment: Please provide an [MCV example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Asok I changed it to `var idx`, good catch, but that's not the issue – the function is not even getting called.

Comment: @Blackhole what's missing in my post?

Comment: The "minimal" part. I've been looking for the `ngClick` directive for a long time!

Comment: Interesting... It can't be `ng-repeat` because I use the `ngClick` directive inside the `ngRepeat` all the time. I am going to post an answer to go over a couple things that strike me which is too long for a comment.

Comment: It should work just fine. I suspect the error is in some portion of you app which is not shown. Can you provide a fiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: @Blackhole I minimised the HTML a bit, hope that helps

Comment: @Sebastian I've reproduced my entire app. I'm not sure how to make a fiddle since the API I am creating the resource with is not public.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NGT3yO3ovNTkm0b9vZHx?p=preview commented the API call but all clicks work just fine

Comment: @Sebastian thanks, but I need to figure out how to make it work with the API call. so it's the binding to the resource that's breaking it?